# Unwanted redirect with form submit

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I just transfered my codeigniter proejct from my wamp server to my nearly free speech server and have been experiencing some weird issues. I'm using a mod_rewrite that I found online to remove the infamous 'index.php' from the url, and I think it is causing a redirect when I submit my form, losing the post data.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the script that the form was calling, I was checking to see if there was post data. If there is no post data, I redirect to a 404 error (this is to prevent people from calling the script via the url). So after uploading the site, I was getting 404 errors with every form submit, suggesting that there was no data being sent. However, for debug purposes, I removed all the code from the script and discovered that submitting the form now loads a blank page. Since a form isn't supposed to actually load a new page, this suggests that the script is redirecting to itself, thus losing the post data and then finally meeting my post data test and redirecting to 404.

Any ideas on why this redirect is happening? This is really really important, and I'll be very grateful for any suggestions!

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't occur because of your `.htaccess` file. There's no redirect flag in your rules. try to send the HTTP request to URL containing `/index.php/`. If you get the same problem, It doesn't related to `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I rewrote the action of the form to include the index.php and this solved the issue. I can use this workaround for the time being (because I'm desperate for time), but I'd really like to know what is going on here for future projects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server doesn't have mod_rewrite enabled.

try to remove the IfModule mod_rewrite.c and IfModule tags to see if 
you get a internal server error..

Hashem Qolami is right theres no redirect flag so your codeigniter router is redirecting...

Comment: I've read all to documentation I could find about the server and they claim that mod_rewrite is enabled. I just tried what you asked though and had the same result.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is definitely on the NearlyFreeSpeech servers. That is not the issue.